# Multiarmed-bandit problem, why can't we use brute force method to tackle this problem

Tags: reinforcement-learning, multiarmed-bandit

since in multiarmed-bandit problem, we can choose which arm to take and get the corresponding reward, however, why can't we conduct a lot of choice of each arm and estimate their probabilities of the reward of each arm just like brute force way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Because that would make less money.

Imagine that there are three machines. Two of them are terrible and have almost no rewards whatsoever. One of them is amazing and has a huge average reward. If your strategy is to try each one of them a huge number of times to very accurately estimate their rewards, you have wasted a huge number of pulls on the bad machines that you could have used on the good machine.

A key part of the definition of the problem is that *you can only pull one lever at a time*. This is why people talk about the problem as being about "the exploitation vs. exploration tradeoff". Let's say I give you 1000 pulls, and you want to maximize your overall winnings by the end of those pulls. Each pull you spend on figuring out the probabilities (i.e., exploration) is a pull you didn't spend on whichever machine you thought was the best at the time (i.e., exploitation).

Comment: For OP's reference, see the comparison between A/B testing and MAB here: https://vwo.com/blog/multi-armed-bandit-algorithm/

Comment: If OP is interested in a citation for such a claim, this point is made in S. L. Scott "A Modern Bayesian Look at the Multi-Armed Bandit." *Applied Stochastic Models in Business & Industry.* 2010.

Answer (score -2):

Suppose the multiarmed-bandit problem is the game of Go. How reasonable does it sound to just try every possible move on every possible board and estimate their expected rewards?

Comment: However, the action-state space of multiarmed-bandit problem is not as large as the game of Go.

Comment: @AlexanderYau Go is one instance of the multiarmed bandit problem.